# PL/SQL select records with the latest two dates

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I have a table where i store the Customer id and the date they logged in.

```
Cust_ID     REC_DATE            

773209      11/5/2013 4:30:52 PM
817265      11/5/2013 4:31:19 PM
```

And so on

How can i see only the latest two records by date for each customer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the analytic function `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by cust_id order by rec_date desc) as seqnum
      from yourtable t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2;
```